# Xampp. Включить curl после обновления php

Tags: php, curl, xampp

Здравствуйте! Использую сборку Xampp (mysql + apache + php). Сегодня обновил php с версии 5.6 на 7.1, но возникли проблемы с библиотекой curl.
Дело в том что у меня windows 7 64-бит, а xampp использует php x86, видимо из-за этого идет конфликт dll.
При каждом включении apache появляется ошибка:

> Точка входа в процедуру libssh2_scp_recv2 не найдена в библиотеке DLL libssh2.dll

За ней другая:

> Порядковый номер 385 не найден в библиотеке DLL SSLEAY32.dll

После этого apache загружается, но php не использует curl.

Как я пробовал решить проблему:
Пробовал менять php_curl.dll из 64-битной версии php, в итоге ошибки не было, но curl не работал.
Пробовал добавлять ssleay32.dll и libssh2.dll в c:/windows/system32 и c:/windows/sysWOW64 но ошибки остались.

Как правильно активировать curl после обновления php?

Comment: Может вам проще скачать OpenServer и там выбрать x64 версию PHP? (https://ospanel.io/download/)

Comment: Нет, тогда придется тратить время на перенос всех баз данных. Сейчас ведь все работает, просто осталось понять как активировать curl

Comment: И мне помогло. OpenServer(Apache 2.4 php 7.2-7.3, php 7.3). Скопировал libssh2.dll из "C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP_7.2" в "C:\OSPanel\modules\http\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.3\bin".

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/520921)

Answer (score 3):

Если у кого-нибудь возникнет эта же проблема: нужно перенести файлы libeay32.dll, libssh2.dll и ssleay32.dll из папки php в папку xampp/apache/bin

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, советую все же отметить, что это именно правильный ответ на вопрос и наверно стоит закрыть сам вопрос :)

Comment: Мне тоже помогло. Спасибо за поднятый вопрос. "...Точка входа в процедуру libssh2_scp_recv2 не найдена в библиотеке DLL libssh2.dll...". Закинул libssh2.dll в папку C:\OSPanel\modules\php\PHP-5.5 .